# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```py
from sklearn.cluster.bicluster import SpectralCoclustering
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
def number_normalizer(tokens):
    """
    Map all numeric tokens to a placeholder.
    For many applications, tokens that begin with a number are not directly
    useful, but the fact that such a token exists can be relevant.  By applying
    this form of dimensionality reduction, some methods may perform better.
    """
        
    return ("#NUMBER" if token[0].isdigit() else token for token in tokens)
    
    
class NumberNormalizingVectorizer(TfidfVectorizer):
    
    def build_tokenizer(self):
        tokenize = super(NumberNormalizingVectorizer, self).build_tokenizer()
        return lambda doc: list(number_normalizer(tokenize(doc)))

vectorizer = NumberNormalizingVectorizer(stop_words='english', min_df=5)
cocluster = SpectralCoclustering(n_clusters=5, svd_method='arpack', random_state=0)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
cocluster.fit(X)
```

I choose SpectralCoclustering to cluster about 30k tweets, everything went well before fit the data X into "cocluster".

It raises the error shown below.

```
.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 43, in _assert_all_finite
    " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Then I typed the code as error reported, but it's "False". It should be True when the error occured, right?

So is there anything more to find the bug? Thanks!

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L43

```
>>> X.dtype.char in np.typecodes['AllFloat'] and not np.isfinite(X.sum()) and not np.isfinite(X).all()
False
```

Comment: You should post some data samples which produces this error.

Comment: Also in the last line change `np.isfinite(X).all()` to `np.isfinite(X).any()`

Comment: @VivekKumar The source code https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L43, said it's .all() , so why change it to any()?

Comment: Ahh yes. My bad, i overlooked the `not` in front of it. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered a similar problem with another `sklearn`-module today, the following trouble-shooting helped me:

- Try to reproduce the error when your input data are not interesting. Replace you 30k big numbers by 30 integers between 0 and 10.
  (In my case, I was not able to reproduce the error that way.)
- Check for `inf`/`NaN` values in your data. If there are any, replace them with a constant. For example, replace `inf` by `LARGE_NUMBER`.
  (In my case, the error still did not go away.)
- Make your constant `LARGE_NUMBER` smaller. It might be that the difference between 10^100 and 10^10 is not too important, if your actual data range between -100 and 100.
  (In my case, the error message changed (first success). So I made my `LARGE_NUMBER` yet smaller, and then the error was gone.)

I suppose that this behaviour came (in my case) from the fact that the `sklearn`-module uses the exponential function sometimes. Therefore your method might call another function where one of the parameters is `inf`, although your input did not contain such values.